# Latest Facebook SDK opens safari get reject in app store?

Tags: ios, facebook, sdk

In app using latest Facebook app to login and share redirect to safari to authenticate app login details.I am already got app reject from app store to open goole login in safari.so using latest facebookSDK get reject in app store? thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you show us the rejection notice?

Comment: 10.6: Apple and our customers place a high value on simple, refined, creative, well thought through interfaces. They take more work but are worth it. Apple sets a high bar. If your user interface is complex or less than very good, it may be rejected
10.6

We found the following issues with the user interface of your app:

The app opens a web page in mobile Safari for logging in to Google plus, then returns the user to the app. The user should be able log in without opening Safari first.

Comment: hope victor's post helps you :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27918011/apple-rejected-app-10-6-because-facebook-opens-safari-to-login

Comment: this above is got previous google plus reject reseon

Comment: can u show  your Facebook permission details,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

> if you added more than these permission you need to submit for Facebook in your app, then Facebook takes the 7 -10 working days for check. if everything is fine you can upload your app in App Store else your app has rejected.

and [Facebook submission process](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review)

if it is not the error for your app please ref this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27918011/apple-rejected-app-10-6-because-facebook-opens-safari-to-login)