# Facebook Login in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I implemented Facebook Login in my app & its works fine as follow:

1) **If Facebook app is installed** then take login info via native FB app & redirect to my app

2)  **If Facebook app is NOT installed** it will redirect to safari for login & come back to my app

**Problem**
I want to use Safari for always for Login info even though native Facebook app is installed

How can I achieve this?

**Thanks**

Comment: I guess it is not possible.Because by default Facebook integration is linked up like this.If FB App exists means it will login through FB App.Otherwise it will redirect to Safari.

Comment: If you use facebook SDK 4.3 and in ios9 then it is default to open facebbok in safari.

Comment: @IOSDeveloper, yes, thanks for your answer. But I need to use native app for login in iOS 9, I know my question is wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help you..

```
FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
login.loginBehavior=FBSDKLoginBehaviorWeb;
[login logInWithReadPermissions:@[@"email"] [login logInWithReadPermissions:@[@"email"] handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {

    } else if (result.isCancelled) {

    } else {
        // here success login
    }
}];
```

Comment: My question is wrong, I need to use native app for login in iOS 9

Answer (score 1):

If you launch in safari Apple probably reject your app because of the following guideline.

```
10.6
Apple and our customers place a high value on simple, refined, creative,
well thought through interfaces. They take more work but are worth it.
Apple sets a high bar. If your user interface is complex or less than very
good, it may be rejected
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27918011/apple-rejected-app-10-6-because-facebook-opens-safari-to-login)

I think you might want to use the Facebook SDK's embedded browser.

Comment: FBSDK also says it will derive best login behaviour and new sdk always open a safari view controller on ios 9 and below this version it opens FB app, although FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
login.loginBehavior=FBSDKLoginBehaviorWeb;  can be used always to open embedded FB webview.

Comment: My question is wrong, I need to use native app for login in iOS 9

Answer (score 1):

FBSDKLoginManager have the property loginBehavior. You need set it with FBSDKLoginBehaviorBrowser.

```
FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
login.loginBehavior = FBSDKLoginBehaviorBrowser;
[login logInWithReadPermissions:@[@"email"] [login logInWithReadPermissions:@[@"email"] handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {

    } else if (result.isCancelled) {

    } else {
        // here success login
    }
}];
```

More info you could found in [FBSDKLoginBehavior enum](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/current/class/FBSDKLoginManager/#typedefs)

Comment: @Mosep, maybe Facebook implement just one solution for this issue) I suppose, result.isCancelled is the important addition.

Comment: My question is wrong, I need to use native app for login in iOS 9

Comment: @user2526811 login.loginBehavior = FBSDKLoginBehaviorNative;

Comment: @HDmast, but what happen if Facebook app is not installed?

Comment: @user2526811, /*! Attempts log in through the native Facebook app. If the Facebook app is
   not installed on the device, falls back to \c FBSDKLoginBehaviorBrowser. This is the
   default behavior.
   */
  FBSDKLoginBehaviorNative = 0